# ¿Programación orientada a objetos (OOP) mejora el rendimiento de programas de este tipo?

Tags: python, poo

Estoy haciendo un programa que tiene un ciclo principal, un ciclo `for` que ejecuta unas condiciones por todos los elementos de una lista. Ahora mismo, la parte del código que interesa se parece a esta:

```
stdin = "Sin texto 'en texto'"
stdin = list(stdin)

for arg in stdin:
    if arg == "\'" or arg == "\"":
        text = not text
        if text == False:
            lstash.append(stash)
        lstash.clear()
```

Así con otras condiciones, como saber si está entre corchetes, cosas así, y en vez de builtins en Python, tengo funciones importadas de otros archivos míos, y quería saber si la programación orientada a objetos puede mejorar el rendimiento.

Comment: El rendimiento de una aplicación no depende del paradigma usado (POO, programación funcional, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, en principio el rendimiento no debería depender del paradigma de programación utilizado. Sin embargo en la práctica sí que depende un poco, dependiendo de cómo el compilador/intérprete implemente el paradigma. Por ejemplo, un estilo funcional podría ser más eficiente que un estilo imperativo para procesar listas o arrays si el intérprete tiene una implementación interna más eficiente de los bucles necesarios, o es capaz de paralelizar automáticamente los bucles entre varias CPUs (no es el caso de Python, pero sí cuando utilizas ciertas librerías de terceros).

En el caso de Python, usar OOP no va a mejorar la eficiencia, sino acaso empeorarla un poco, ya que los objetos son una "capa intermedia" que se interpone en las llamadas a los métodos. En general, invocar un método de un objeto va a llevar al intérprete más operaciones que invocar una función en un módulo (entre otras cosas hay un nivel de indirección más, al tener que buscar primero el objeto y después el método dentro de él).

Esto no implica que no deba usarse OOP porque "penaliza" la ejecución. La penalización es tan diminuta que no debe tenerse en cuenta. Pero sí implica que el rendimiento no ha de ser la razón que te lleve a elegir un paradigma u otro. Por el contrario, debes usar el paradigma que mejor se adapte al problema, y que por tanto produzca un código más sencillo y legible, y por tanto fácil de depurar y mantener.

### Otros detalles

Fuera ya de tu pregunta, cuando tienes una variable booleana, mirar `if variable == True` o `if variable == False` es mal estilo. Basta poner `if variable` o `if not variable`, respectivamente.

Otra recomendación es utilizar nombres de variables que expliquen lo que hacen. Eso ayuda mucho también a hacer el código legible. En tu caso, por ejemplo, no deberías usar `stdin` como nombre de variable, ya que ese término tiene un significado bien conocido en programación: "la entrada estándar" (de la que leen los programas, normalmente el teclado). Yo lo llamaría `text`, puesto que eso es lo que contiene. Por otro lado, para iterar letra a letra no necesitas convertirlo en lista. Puedes hacer `for c in text` directamente.

Tu variable `text` en cambio contiene un booleano, por lo que un nombre mejor podría ser `is_text` (debes leerlo como una pregunta, cuya respuesta será "verdadero" o "falso").

Asimismo no usaría `arg` como índice de bucle. La palabra `arg` se usa generalmente para referirse a "argumentos" (parámetros, ya sea de una función o de línea de comandos). En este caso esa variable contendrá un caracter del texto que está siendo procesado, así que ¿por qué no llamarlo mejor `character`?

Una forma de saber si un carácter es uno entre varios conocidos, además de compararlo uno a uno con un `or` como tú has hecho, es mirar si está en o no en una lista de caracteres dada: `if character in lista`.

Tu código quedaría entonces así, en mi opinión más legible (no he tocado `stash` ni `lstash` porque no entiendo qué hacen, y no muestras cómo se inicializan):

```
text = "Sin texto 'en texto'"
quotes = "\'\""
is_text = False

for character in text:
    if character in quotes:
        is_text = not is_text
        if is_text:
            lstash.append(stash)
        lstash.clear()
```

Como ves se trata de que, eligiendo nombres de variables apropiados, el código se pueda leer casi como pseudocódigo.